# Flutter Can't access function defined in BLoC

Tags: flutter, dart, state, bloc

I'm trying to implement a bottom navigation bar with bloc. I defined a function, which will control the navigation. The function is inside a BLoC. My problem is, that I cannot access this function. I tried to define it outside an -function, but it still doesn't work. What did I do wrong here?

landingpage.dart relevant part

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/prensentation/LandingPage/bloc/landing_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
.
.
bottomNavigationBar: BlocBuilder<LandingBloc, NavigationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: state.index,
            showSelectedLabels: false,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "home"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: "settings"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.account_box), label: "account")
            ],
            onTap: (index) {

               //this doesn't work
              if (index == 0) {
                BlocProvider.of<LandingBloc>(context).
                    .getNavBarItem(NavbarItem.settings)
              } else if (index == 1) {
                BlocProvider.of<LandingBloc>(context);
                    .getNavBarItem(NavbarItem.settings);
              } else if (index == 2) {
                BlocProvider.of<LandingBloc>(context);
                    .getNavBarItem(NavbarItem.profile);
              }
            },
          );
```

landing_bloc, landing_event, landing_state

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/prensentation/LandingPage/nav_bar_items.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'landing_event.dart';
part 'landing_state.dart';


//BLoC
class LandingBloc extends Bloc<LandingEvent, NavigationState> {
  LandingBloc() : super(NavigationState(NavBarItem.home, 0)) {
    on<LandingInitial>((event, emit) {
      // TODO: implement event handler
      void getNavBarItem(NavBarItem navbarItem) {
        switch (navbarItem) {
          case NavBarItem.home:
            emit(NavigationState(NavBarItem.home, 0));
            break;
          case NavBarItem.setting:
            emit(NavigationState(NavBarItem.setting, 1));
            break;
          case NavBarItem.profile:
            emit(NavigationState(NavBarItem.profile, 2));
            break;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
//Events
part of 'landing_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class LandingEvent {}

class LandingInitial extends LandingEvent {}


//States
part of 'landing_bloc.dart';

class NavigationState extends Equatable {
  final NavBarItem navbarItem;
  final int index;

  NavigationState(this.navbarItem, this.index);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [this.navbarItem, this.index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bloc we add a event from UI part and Bloc do certain operation and emit a state. And here you have made a function inside and event code which is wrong you should add a event where you are trying to call the bloc function.

And i don't see you have use-case for Bloc you should be using the Cubit either, it have the similar functionality you are trying to do, calling a cubit function and do operation and emit state simple.

Check out this article for [Cubit](https://blog.flutterando.com.br/cubit-a-simple-solution-for-app-state-management-in-flutter-66ab5279ef73)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `BlocProvider` in your page to create bloc.

```
BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => LandingBloc(),
      child: ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`getNavBarItem` must be the class's method. Try:

```dart
class LandingBloc extends Bloc<LandingEvent, NavigationState> {
  Future<void> getNavBarItem(NavBarItem navbarItem) async {
    // ...
  }

  LandingBloc() : super(NavigationState(NavBarItem.home, 0)) {
    // ...
  }
  
  // ...
}
```

```dart
BlocProvider.of<LandingBloc>(context).getNavBarItem(NavbarItem.settings);
```

Agree with @pixel, you should check `Cubit` to stuff like this better.